# zend framework zend_mail not sending email

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-mail

Inherited a zend framework application version 1.12
and as of recent stopped sending emails.

indexcontroller.php

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail('UTF-8');
                $mail->addTo($sender_email);
                $mail->setSubject("Result of Payment Transaction (Success)");
                ob_start();
                include APPLICATION_PATH . 
                 '/views/scripts/file.phtml';
                $message = ob_get_clean();

                $mail->setBodyText($message);
                $mail->setFrom('email@mail.com');
                $mail->send();
```

application.ini

```
                   ;EMAIL SETTTING
resources.mail.transport.type = Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp
resources.mail.transport.host = "smtp.gmail.com"
resources.mail.transport.port = 465 
resources.mail.transport.auth = "login"
resources.mail.transport.username = "mail@emil.com"
resources.mail.transport.password = "pass"
resources.mail.transport.ssl = "ssl"
```

Bootstrap.php

```
         $emailConfig = array(
        'auth' => 'login',
        'username' => Zend_Registry::get('config')->email->username,
        'password' => Zend_Registry::get('config')->email->password,
        'ssl' => Zend_Registry::get('config')->email->protocol,
        'port' => Zend_Registry::get('config')->email->port
    ); 

    $mailTransport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp(
            Zend_Registry::get('config')->email->server, $emailConfig);
    Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($mailTransport);
```

Outputting error I am getting is,

> Exception information:
>   Message: Could not open socket
>
> Stack trace:
>   1. library/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Smtp.php(167): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Abstract->_connect('ssl://smtp.gmai...')
>   2. library/Zend/Mail/Transport/Smtp.php(199): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Smtp->connect()
>   3. library/Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php(348): Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp->_sendMail()

I looked at if the sever is connecting which it is,
telnet smtp.gmail.com 465
connected
Username password is correct I also attempt to change to tls but still no success

any feedback or some reference would be much appreciated

Comment: Is the page blank because your script doesn't output anything or because an error occurred and you have `display_errors` turned off?

Comment: I thought I had all my display_errors on but I didnt, so now Im getting my errors.. Message: Could not open socket ..so I will start troubleshooting ..thanks